# wn.synset('whale.n.01') returns the wrong synset

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

```
print(wn.synset('whale.n.01'))
```

This code prints:

```
Synset('giant.n.04')
```

I have `from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn`. Everything else is working fine.

Comment: Hey there. Could you add a bit more information around the "from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn" message?

Comment: yes, this isn't a message it is an python import written at the top of my program which allows me to have access to WordNet and its functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sense of whale, 'whale.n.02' is the mammal. See below from wordnet online demo http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn